# Sorting values with tolerance

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I'm trying to sort a datatable of objects with X and Y values so that it gets sorted by Y and then by X. This all works fine now, but I was wondering if there is a way to add a tolerance value so that when two Y values are within that tolerance range, that they are seen as the same and get sorted by the corresponded X value only. 
For example:

- Object 1 has `X=4 and Y=4.1`.
- Object 2 has `X=6 and Y=4`.

If the 0.1 difference is within the given tolerance, I want them to sort as 1 and then 2, but now it sorts as 2 and then 1 because of this difference.
It's part of a Revit API project, but I think this is just a general C# question. The table gets data from a list of objects called `objectList`.
Is there any way to accomplish what I want?

Code:

```
// Create table
DataTable obTable = new DataTable();

// id
DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn();
idColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
idColumn.ColumnName = "id";
obTable.Columns.Add(idColumn);

// X
DataColumn xColumn = new DataColumn();
xColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
xColumn.ColumnName = "X";
obTable.Columns.Add(xColumn);

// Y
DataColumn yColumn = new DataColumn();
yColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
yColumn.ColumnName = "Y";
obTable.Columns.Add(yColumn);

// get data from objectList
foreach (FamilyInstance ob in objectList)
{
    int id = ob.Id.IntegerValue;
    LocationPoint L = ob.Location as LocationPoint;
    int X = (int)L.Point.X;
    int Y = (int)L.Point.Y;

    DataRow row;
    row = obTable.NewRow();

    row["id"] = id;
    row["X"] = X;
    row["Y"] = Y;

    obTable.Rows.Add(row);
}

// sort table
DataView dv = new DataView(obTable);
dv.Sort = "Y ASC, X ASC";
DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanx XD

Comment: You can sort the objectList before you insert into DataTable. This can be done by implementing a Comparison(T) Delegate. See here for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @lamandy but can you sort a list by 2 values then? So sort it by Y and then by X if the Y values are the same (or within the given tolerance). That's the sole purpose why I'm using a datatable to be honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static int CompareWithThreshold(FamilyInstance obj1, FamilyInstance obj2)
{
   LocationPoint point1 = obj1.Location as LocationPoint;
   LocationPoint point2 = obj2.Location as LocationPoint;
   double x1 = point1.Point.X;
   double y1 = point1.Point.Y;
   double x2 = point2.Point.X;
   double y2 = point2.Point.Y;
   double diff = y1 - y2;
   if (diff >= -0.1 && diff <= 0.1)
   {
       return x1.CompareTo(x2);
   }
   else
   {
       return y1.CompareTo(y2);
   }
}
```

To sort your list, just

```
objectList.Sort(CompareWithThreshold);
```

Comment: This works! Just had to capitalize `compareTo` and `sort`. Thanks!